# How to download file using IHttpClientFactory in .Net Core 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

In my web application (.net Core 2.2) I want to add the functionality of downloading a PDF file.

When the user clicks "download" - POST is sent to WebAPI and the server ask different server for PDF file by hardcoded URL (invisible to the user) and the file is passed to the user.

I was trying to use `IHttpClientFactory`

Startup:

```
services.AddHttpClient("demo", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.africau.edu/");
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/pdf");
});
```

Method for returns PDF file:

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> GetPdfFile()
{    
    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("demo");
    var uri = new UriBuilder(client.BaseAddress + "images/default/sample.pdf").Uri;
    var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri);

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf"));
}
```

Unfortunately it returns file `download.json` with: *{"fileStream":{"needsDrain":true,"canRead":true,"canWrite":false,"canSeek":false*

---

**@EDIT**

it seems that it's because I had `Task<IActionResult>` in my Controller instead of `Task<FileStreamResult>` but what if i prefer to returns ActionResult?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPdf()
{
    var result = await _service.GetPdfFile();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: It seems like some information is missing from this question. What is consuming the "GetPdfFile" endpoint? Where are you seeing the "download.json" file being downloaded; is that when you hit the "GetPdfFile" endpoint from a browser, or is there another layer between the browser and "GetPdfFile"?

Comment: UI -> Controll WebApi -> GetPdfFile Method.

download.json is returned to the User. Who clicked "download" on UI. So it seems that API returns some file.

Comment: It seems your "Control WebApi" is serializing a stream to JSON instead of returning the stream's content. What is the contents of the action method in that layer?

Comment: @Arcanox I edited post. This method has reteurn type: Task<IActionResult> and has only: `return OK(result)` which is result from this method.

Comment: Can you update your question to show that full method as well? That way I can post a relevant answer. Using `Ok(result)` will serialize `result` using the default serializer and return the serialized content as a `200 OK` response, which would explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @Arcanox I added, if i will change it to `Task<FileStreamResult>` then is fine, but i prefer `ActionResult` since I can return `NotFound()` as well.

Comment: Don’t return `Ok(result)` but just return `result` directly.

Answer (score 1):

In your `GetPdf` method, you're passing a `FileStreamResult` to the `Ok()` method. This will serialize the `FileStreamResult` using the default serializer and send it to the client, hence why you're seeing the JSON.

Usually your service layer should not return an MVC `WhateverResult` object but rather an object intended to represent the actual data being retrieved - in your case this would be a PDF file. The easiest way to solve your particular case would probably be to do the following:

- change `GetPdfFile` to return `Task<FileStream>` instead of `Task<FileStreamResult>`

  - remember to change its return statement to `return stream;`
- change the return statement of `GetPdf` to `return File(result, "application/pdf");`

This will allow your service layer to return the PDF file as a stream, and then have your `GetPdf` endpoint return that stream as a file with the `application/pdf` file type.

Comment: What is `result` in `return File(result, "application/pdf");` ?

Comment: @DiPix it would be the return value from `GetPdfFile`, which, after making my suggested changes, should be a `FileStream`. You could name the variable whatever you want.